# How do I resolve this error please "Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

```
fun main() {
    fun convert(x: Double, converter: (Double) -> Double) : Double{
        val result = converter(x)
        println("$x is converted to $result")
        return result
    }
    fun convertFive(converter: (Int) -> Double) : Double {
        val result = converter(5)
        println("5 is converted to $result")
        return result
    }

    convert(20.0) { it * 1.8 + 32}
    convertFive { it * 1.8 + 32 }
}
```

// i got this error when i updated my intelliJ Idea and ran this
//

> Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Can you kindly post the rest of the error? It may be that you need to update your Java, Kotlin, or gradle versions

Comment: That's all i see and nothing more

Comment: There is no problem with the code in the question.  (It compiles and runs fine in my IntelliJ.)  It must be a problem with your set-up.

Comment: This is the new error it's showing                              
"Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.NOClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij,pom.java.LanguageLevel"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that the current version of the Kotlin compiler (1.4.31, 1.5-M1) doesn't work on JDK 16. Please use JDK < 16 for now.
Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45566.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: It didn't work for me I tried many versions !!

Comment: I think Kotlin 1.5.10 works with JDK 16 now, try updating Kotlin

Answer (score 6):

Try `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Comment: Even if you do the steps in described in the accepted answer, this was a necessary step. In my case as the issue persisted up to the point I did what was suggested here.